# I am using fs module readdir but I keep getting this error (Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir)

Tags: javascript, fs

I created a videos folder with videos in my react folder structure, I want to access the files in this folder and I came across the fs module, but no matter how many different solutions I tried, it shows that the file does not exist even though it is there.

```js
fs.readdir('./src/videos', (err, files) => {
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log(files);
        files.forEach(file => {
          console.log(file);
        })
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, make sure the path is correct.
Check where the folder is in relation to where you are running the code from.
Check the folder's name - make sure you don't have a typo.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I was typing the path wrong. Thank you